# How to create the logic for use as an input for redirect?

Tags: html

I'd like to create something similar to the zip code "submit" [here](https://webuyhouses.com). The basic principle is to create an input box that a visitor can input their zip code. Once they hit submit, the site would redirect to the appropriate page. Our plan is to create a page for each city in California and use zip codes to direct the visitor to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the form and with Javascript get the value of the zip field and so a redirect:

```
<input type="number" id="zip" />
<button onClick="goTo()">Go</button>
```

So when the button is click we call the function `goTo()`

```
function goTo() {
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    window.location.replace("http://site-to-redirect.com/" + zip);
}
```

And that function will do the redirect to the page you need with the value of the field.

Full demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fmontes/h6o4c9qy/4/).